# React: using localStorage with React hooks, how would I make my components not reload unless the button is clicked?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, local-storage, react-hooks

Currently my app is accessing external data with fetch on mounting of the main component and whenever I reload the page it reloads the data and resets local storage items that I have linked to it.

However, what I would like is:
1) Very first time user opens the page the whole dataset must be loaded
2) If user removes any of the items in the table, then closes the tab or reloads the page, those removed items should not reappear in the dataset and the table (unless the "reload" button is clicked)

My main component currently looks like this:

```
function App() {
  const DEFAULT_ERROR = null
  const DEFAULT_IS_LOADED = false
  const DEFAULT_DATASET = []
  const DEFAULT_INPUT_VALUE = ''
  const DEFAULT_DROPDOWN_VALUE = 'year'
  const DEFAULT_GRAPH_DATA = []

  const URL = 'https://reqres.in/api/unknown'

 const [ error, setError ] = React.useState(DEFAULT_ERROR)
 const [ isLoaded, setIsLoaded ] = React.useState(DEFAULT_IS_LOADED)
 const [ dataset, setDataset ] = React.useState(DEFAULT_DATASET)

 const [ inputValue, setInputValue ] = React.useState(DEFAULT_INPUT_VALUE)
 const [ dropdownValue, setDropdownValue ] = React.useState(DEFAULT_DROPDOWN_VALUE)

 const { graphData, setGraphData } = React.useState(DEFAULT_GRAPH_DATA)

 localStorage.setItem('hasBeenLoaded', false)
 let hasBeenLoaded = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('hasBeenLoaded'))

 if (!hasBeenLoaded) {
  localStorage.setItem('hasBeenLoaded', true)
  hasBeenLoaded = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('hasBeenLoaded'))
  console.log(hasBeenLoaded)

  React.useEffect(() => {
    requestData(URL, setIsLoaded, setDataset, setError)
  }, [])
}
```

I tried storing a value in the local storage that tracks whether the app has been already loaded on users PC so it won't re-run the useEffect with fetch request, but for some reason it still seems to be running and any of the table items that I delete re-appear on reload.

The `requestData` function is the following:

```
function requestData(url, setIsLoaded, setDataset, setError) {
  return fetch(url)
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(
      (result) => { 
        setIsLoaded(true)

        for (let i=0; i < result.data.length; i++) {
          localStorage.setItem(result.data[i].id, JSON.stringify(result.data[i]))

          setDataset(
            prevDataset => [...prevDataset, JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(result.data[i].id))]
          )
        }
      },
      (error) => {
        setIsLoaded(true)
        setError(error)
      }
    )
 }
```

What should I do in order to make my component work as planned? Here is my [pen](https://codepen.io/konstantinkrumin/pen/KKVMxaY?editors=0011) just in case.

Best regards,
Konstantin

Comment: @LoicH Where did you get the idea that you can't persist localStorage?

Comment: It actually seems to save hasBeenLoaded as 'true' in the local storage on the first load, but I still can't get it to not reload the data for some reason

Comment: You are setting `hasBeenLoaded` as false in storage before even checking it. Suggest you think through all that `hasBeenLoaded` logic some more

Comment: @LoicH localStorage is actually the only thing you can reliably persist in the browser lol

Comment: my bad i thought closing window/re-opening it clears the localstorage

Answer (score 0):

As @charlietfl said, you are setting the value of `hasBeenLoaded` to false always, so it will fetch the data always, the logic for this to work would be:

1. check if the `hasBeenLoaded` variable exists in the LocalStorage
2. if not, call your `requestData` method (you don't even need the `useEffect`)
3. if yes, don't do anything

Then when the user clicks the reload button, then you set the variable to false

```
const hasBeenLoaded = localStorage.getItem('hasBeenLoaded')

if(!hasBeenLoaded){
  requestData(URL, setIsLoaded, setDataset, setError)
  localStorage.setItem('hasBeenLoaded', true)
}
```